# Convert ProofNotes to $ \mathrm\LaTeX $ logic expression

Tags: string-manipulation, latex, logic

The following code will generate some ProofNotes:

```
PL = {ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, True] == p], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, False] == p], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, True] == True], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, False] == False], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, p] == p], ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, p] == p],
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, not[not[p]] == p], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, q] == or[q, p]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, q] == and[q, p]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[or[p, q], r] == or[p, or[q, r]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[and[p, q], r] == and[p, and[q, r]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, and[q, r]] == and[or[p, q], or[p, r]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, or[q, r]] == or[and[p, q], and[p, r]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, not[and[p, q]] == or[not[p], not[q]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, not[or[p, q]] == and[not[p], not[q]]], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, and[p, q]] == p], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, or[p, q]] == p], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, or[p, not[p]] == True], 
  ForAll[{p, q, r}, and[p, not[p]] == False]}
proof = FindEquationalProof[
  ForAll[{a, b, c}, 
   or[and[not[a], c], or[and[not[b], a], and[not[b], c]]] == 
    or[and[not[a], c], and[not[b], a]]], PL]
proof["ProofNotebook"]
```

This proves logic statements with logical equivalence, in this case it's proving:

```
or[and[not[a], c], or[and[not[b], a], and[not[b], c]]] == 
    or[and[not[a], c], and[not[b], a]]
```

$$(\neg a\land c)\lor((\neg b\land a)\lor(\neg b\land c))\equiv(\neg a\land c)\lor(\neg b\land a)$$

In  $ \mathrm\LaTeX $ this is

```
(\neg a\land c)\lor((\neg b\land a)\lor(\neg b\land c))\equiv(\neg a\land c)\lor(\neg b\land a)
```

And here is some lines of the proof notes:

```
and[or[c,a],not[and[a,b]]]==or[and[not[a],c],and[not[b],a]]
```

$$(c\lor a)\land\neg(a\land b)\equiv(\neg a \land  c) \lor  (\neg b \land  a)$$

In  $ \mathrm\LaTeX $ this is:

```
(c\lor a)\land\neg(a\land b)\equiv(\neg a \land  c) \lor  (\neg b \land  a)
```

---

```
and[or[c,a],or[not[a],not[b]]]==or[and[not[a],c],and[not[b],a]]
```

$$(a \lor c) \land  (\neg a \lor  \neg b)\equiv (\neg a \land  c) \lor  (\neg b \land  a)$$

In  $ \rm\LaTeX $ which is:

```
(a \lor c) \land  (\neg a \lor  \neg b)\equiv (\neg a \land  c) \lor  (\neg b \land  a)
```

How do I do this conversion?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`TeXForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html) to do most of the work for you. You only need to replace your custom operators with the built-in ones, so that `TeXForm` knows which symbols to use:

```
makeTeX[expr_] := 
 HoldForm[expr] /. {and -> And, or -> Or, not -> Not, Equal -> Congruent} // 
  TeXForm

makeTeX[and[or[c, a], not[and[a, b]]] == or[and[not[a], c], and[not[b], a]]]
(* ((c\lor a)\land \neg (a\land b))\equiv ((\neg a\land c)\lor (\neg b\land a)) *)
```

> $((c\lor a)\land \neg (a\land b))\equiv ((\neg a\land c)\lor (\neg b\land a))$

Note the use of [`HoldForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) to prevent the expression from evaluation when the built-in operators are substituted in.